# SwiftyJSON, can't turn json into a double

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to build a cryptocurrency app that tells you the price of Cardano via an API. In the 'If Statement' below it goes straight to 'else' but if I change '.double' to '.string' it works fine. I can't figure out why. I'm using SwiftyJSON, Alamofire, Swift4 and Xcode 9

Here is the API:
https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/ada-aud and it should bring back the price e.g 0.47756685

```
func updateCardanoData(json : JSON) {
    if let cardanoResult = json["ticker","price"].double {
        cardanoPriceLabel.text = currencySelected + "\(cardanoResult)"
    } else  {
        cardanoPriceLabel.text = "price unavailable"
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the exact string value you wish to convert to a double? Show the relevant JSON.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your API doesn't actually return a double, but a string.

```
"price":"0.48121602" - this is a string, notice the double quotes
```

A solution would be to cast the string received to a Double like this:

```
if let cardanoResult = json["ticker","price"].string, let doubleResult = Double(cardanoResult) {
        //do stuff with doubleResult
}
```

Comment: it has to be `if let cardanoResult = json["ticker","price"].string, let doubleResult = Double(cardanoResult) {`

Answer (score 0):

Because I don't know the structure of the JSON, I can only say, how to print the error. I don't know, if this a help to you. As the docs of SwiftyJSON state, you can use `error` to get the error, for example:

```
if let cardanoResult = json["ticker","price"].double {
    //do something with the Double value
} else  {
    print(json["ticker","price"].error)
}
```

I hope, this is a help to you, otherwise, please show us the structure of the JSON.